# Invalid table name with table search

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery I am using the following query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `properati-data-public:properties_mx.properties_sell_201***`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1501'
  AND '1810'
```

Where `properati-data-public:properties_mx.properties_sell_201501` is a valid table. When I use the query with multiple tables, I get the following error:

```
Query Failed  
Error: Invalid table name: `properati-data-public:properties_mx.properties_sell_201***`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use:

```
`properati-data-public.properties_mx.properties_sell_20*`
```

Note:

- `.` vs. `:`
- `20*` vs. `201***`

Also put below as a first line in your query to assure you are in Standard SQL mode

```
#standardSQL
```

Comment: Thank you, that got my query running, but it didn't return any records. Any obvious reasons I am missing why that might be happening?

Comment: give me example of actual table name that you would expected to return some rows

Comment: I run `SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM  \`properati-data-public.properties_mx.properties_sell_20*\`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1501' AND '1810'` and it returns 2,762,514 - so you should be good as long as you typed correctly